# Internal HTTP server disabled in IntelliJ. Cannot open the project

Tags: java, httpserver, intellij-14

When I open my project in IntelliJ this error is popping up.

[image]
Internal HTTP server disabled: Cannot start internal HTTP server. Git integration, JavaScript debugger and LiveEdit may operate with errors. Please check your firewall settings and restart IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: (1) Do you actually lneed to use Git integration, JavaScript debugger and LiveEdit?  (2) What did you see when you checked your firewall settings?

Comment: (1) I need to use Git integration, Java Script debugger and LiveEdit  (2) Firewall settings disabled

Comment: Is it possible for you to enable the firewall setting that would allow your computer to serve HTTP?

Comment: Since I'm not working on my machine, I don't have permission to change Firewall settings.

Comment: Maybe you should talk to your system administrator.  I think you're saying that you need to run an HTTP server on the computer, but you don't  have permission to run an HTTP server on the computer.  The Stack Overflow community can't really help you with this.

Comment: මෙත්මි I think this error occurs during the maven import dependencies.. it seems that maven doesn't have permission to access to the internet

Answer (score 2):

Try like below

Run **command prompt as administrator**

and run this command `netsh winsock reset`

Restart your PC

Answer (score 1):

this works form me but i can't say why

[BASE FILTERING ENGINE service issues: ERR_NETWORK_ACCESS_DENIED and Can not start internal HTTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36738400/base-filtring-engine-service-issues-err-network-access-denied-and-can-not-start)

Disable stop and restart the BASE FILTRING SERVICE

Comment: Stopping and starting doesn't help but just stopping helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem very similar to this. I would have to use Alupotha's answer a couple times a day. When poking around at what could cause the problem, I realized that my Malware Bytes Anti-malware software could be the cause. I disabled it, and my problem went away. If whoever needs to use Alupotha's answer over and over, maybe checking your malware software could be a good thing to check too.

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps:

1. go to **search panel**
2. write **run**
3. write **services.msc**
4. search for **windows firewall**
5. right click -> **properties**
6. go to startup type and transfert into **Disabled**
7. clic **stop** and *apply* and **ok**
8. restart your *intellij* and enjoy