# BASE FILTERING ENGINE service issues: ERR_NETWORK_ACCESS_DENIED and Can not start internal HTTP server

Tags: r, android-studio, localserver

I have 2 issues.

first: I was on my browser the **ERR_NETWORK_ACCESS_DENIED** error when i try to get to the **R local help server (http://127.0.0.1:xxxx../doc/html/Search?results=1)**

the second I had, when I launch android studio:; the message  **Internal HTTP server disabled: Can not start internal HTTP server. Git integration, JavaScript debugger and LiveEdit May operate with errors. Please check your firewall settings and restart Android Studio**

I try several solutions found on intrnet: flushing dns, restating winsock, disabling antivirus ...
without success

Last resort, I thought of a conflict with a service, I tried a selective start with (msconfig) by turning off all services. AND IT WORKS

After several attempts. I found the service responsible. it was the **BASE filtering ENGINE service** (BFE).

then each time i start windows I disable the service and I stop these dependencies (IPsec Strategy Officer, Windows Firewall, generation modules IKE and AuthIP). then I enable and restart all these services

I do not figure out the problem and how to settle it definitively.

Any idea? thanks

Comment: R is a statistical analysis software.   R Core Team (2016). R: A language and environment for statistical computing. R Foundation for Statistical Computing, Vienna, Austria.  URL https://www.R-project.org/.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to turn off Windows Firewall.

I did it and succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and in the end reinstalled studio, turned on/off the firewall, reset netsh, etc. etc. all failed.

Gradle needed to be upgraded and once upgraded it worked fine.

There was not message to tell me this.

This is what worked for me I hope it helps as there is not much information on this error.