# Android Studio project build: read time out (Windows 10, firewall off, no proxy)

Tags: android, windows, gradle

I am using Windows 10, and just installed Android Studio Arctic Fox Patch 2 (following a Udemy course), and created a new project with a new Android Phone activity "Empty activity".

And when I try to click on "Gradle Sync", the IDE tries to download gradle pom for about 2 minutes and then fails with:

`Read timed out`

I also cannot add any Android Virtual devices as the Internet connection is missing according to the IDE, and it cannot fetch the list of possible Virtual Devices.

I am going crazy since 2 days. I am not using proxy, my Internet download speed is 120Mb, upload is 5Mb, video calls are working normally. I have not changed any project configuration, I am not using a Proxy.

- there are no Proxy settings in my Windows configuration
- there is no global `gradle.properties` file where I could have those proxy settings set (I did a global file search). The project's file does not have any proxy settings (it is generated by the IDE anyway)
- I have tried adding Android Studio (the exes inside the `bin` folder the the Firewall exceptions)
- I have tried disabling Windows Firewall alltogether
- I have tried rebooting with `msconfig` and only the basic Windows services (so no startup apps)
- also tried this: [BASE FILTERING ENGINE service issues: ERR_NETWORK_ACCESS_DENIED and Can not start internal HTTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36738400/base-filtering-engine-service-issues-err-network-access-denied-and-can-not-star)
- also tried this: [Android studio "Cannot start internal HTTP server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889503/android-studio-cannot-start-internal-http-server/24585741#24585741)

Full stack trace:

```
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 4 s 286 ms

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'My First APp'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.0.2/gradle-7.0.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.0.2/gradle-7.0.2.pom'.
               > Read timed out
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.20.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.20.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.20/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.20.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.20/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.20.pom'.
               > Read timed out

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'My First APp'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:75)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:68)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$400(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:51)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:102)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:250)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$withProjectLock$3(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:310)
(...)   org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.copyToCache(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:199)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

Can anyone help me?

Maybe more information, `settings.gradle`:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}
rootProject.name = "My First APp"
include ':app'
```

`build.gradle`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.20"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

inner `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myfirstapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

`gradle.properties`

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app"s APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true
# Kotlin code style for this project: "official" or "obsolete":
kotlin.code.style=official
```

[Bonus information]

The whole thing started working yesterday after I set in my IDE "Automatically detect Proxy settings" instead of "No Proxy", without providing any settings. But then I had to re-install my Android Studio to match the version of the one from the course, and that trick from yesterday is not working anymore. Perhaps that setting in IDE was just a coincidence, but then I have no idea why it worked then and not now.

How can I debug it? I already had similar issues with Docker and Kubernetes development, where I spent a month before giving up. Maybe this is something Windows-specific? How can I stop Windows from blocking the outgoing connections?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48465454/3139995. It is crazy that this is needed in order to make a dev tool work on Windows. I still don't understand the problem.